# Why do I have 1.4 GB of pending crash reports for Firefox?

Tags: firefox, crash, logging, disk-space

[image: screenshot]

Why do I have 1.4 GB of space taken up by [`pending`] crash reports? There is a folder inside of this one (in screenshot) where most of the used space is located. Why on earth is there that much space taken up by *pending* crash reports?

Maybe more importantly, can I just delete all the content in this folder without adverse affects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're pending because you haven't submitted them to firefox.  Delete them unless you care about looking at them

Mozilla has disabled auto submission in all browser versions in response to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1424373

Go to about:crashes in your browser to see pending and submitted crashes and there is a button to remove reports.

Comment: That's odd, I've seen them automatically submitted in the past - how should I submit them and will they delete automatically? (And did I change something to switch auto-crash-reporting off?)

Comment: Mozilla has disabled auto submission in all browser versions in response to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1424373   go to about:crashes in your browser to see pending and submitted crashes and there is a button to remove reports.

Comment: Done, thank you. I'm accepting this answer, and I suggest adding the details in your above comment to the body of the answer.